# how to create sqlite table when object contains another class object in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a demo for expense book

here It was working well, but now I am adding one more field in TransactionModel, and it is category.

here I have created a category model, now I don't know how to create a table that contains class object,

```
//HOW TO ADD FIELD OF CATEGORY IN THIS TABLE
class SqliteHelper{
  static Future<Database> _getdb() async {
    return openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'transactiondb.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) async => await db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE transactiontb(id TEXT NOT NULL,title TEXT NOT NULL,amount INTEGER NOT NULL,isexpense INTEGER NOT NULL);"),
        version: 1);
  }


  static Future<int> addTransaction(TransactionModel transaction) async
  {
    final db=await _getdb();
    return await db.insert('transactiontb', transaction.toJson(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }
}
```

here are my class models

```
class CategoryModel {
  String title;
  IconData iconpath;

  CategoryModel({required this.title, required this.iconpath});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'title': title,
      'iconpath': iconpath,
    };
  }

  factory CategoryModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return CategoryModel(title: map['title'], iconpath: map['iconpath']);
  }
}
```

and transaction model

```
class TransactionModel {
  String id;
  String title;
  int isexpense;
  int amount;
  CategoryModel category;

  TransactionModel(
      {required this.category,
      required this.id,
      required this.title,
      this.isexpense = 1,
      required this.amount});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'isexpense': isexpense,
      'amount': amount,
      'category': category.toMap(),
    };
  }

  factory TransactionModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return TransactionModel(
        id: map['id'],
        title: map['title'],
        amount: map['amount'],
        isexpense: map['isexpense'], category: CategoryModel.fromMap(map['category']));
  }
}
```

Comment: need to know....failing to understand as sqlite does not support objectt datatype